# How do I pass a variable to a QThread object when creating an instance? I'm getting a type error in Qthread.__init__

Tags: qthread, pyside6

I found this sample code using QThread at https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_widgets__thread_signals.html

I modified the code in an attempt to pass a variable to the thread when instantiated based on info I found here:  https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\joe\python\ThreadTest.py", line 22, in start_thread
        instanced_thread = WorkerThread(self, 'c:\testfile.xml')
    File "C:\Users\joe\python\ThreadTest.py", line 44, in __init__
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtCore.QThread.__init__' called with wrong argument types:
    PySide6.QtCore.QThread.__init__(str)
Supported signatures:
    PySide6.QtCore.QThread.__init__(Optional[PySide6.QtCore.QObject] = None)
```

Can someone tell me the proper syntax for passing a variable to a QThread?
I'm using PySide6 and Python 3.9.10.

```py
# Copyright (C) 2022 The Qt Company Ltd.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-Qt-Commercial OR BSD-3-Clause

import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QThread, Signal, Slot
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

# Create a basic window with a layout and a button
class MainForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My Form")
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    # Instantiate and start a new thread
    def start_thread(self):
        instanced_thread = WorkerThread(self, 'c:\testfile.xml')
        instanced_thread.start()

    # Create the Slots that will receive signals
    @Slot(str)
    def update_str_field(self, message):
        print(message)

    @Slot(int)
    def update_int_field(self, value):
        print(value)

# Signals must inherit QObject
class MySignals(QObject):
    signal_str = Signal(str)
    signal_int = Signal(int)

# Create the Worker Thread
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, filename, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        # Instantiate signals and connect signals to the slots
        self.signals = MySignals()
        self.signals.signal_str.connect(parent.update_str_field)
        self.signals.signal_int.connect(parent.update_int_field)
        self.filename = filename

    def run(self):
        # Do something on the worker thread
        a = 1 + 1
        # Emit signals whenever you want
        self.signals.signal_int.emit(a)
        self.signals.signal_str.emit("This text comes to Main thread from our Worker thread.")
        print(self.filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainForm()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Typo. Your `__init__` signature is `filename, parent`, but you're passing the opposite: `WorkerThread(self, 'c:\testfile.xml')`. Change to `WorkerThread('c:\testfile.xml', self)`.

Comment: Also, ``\`` is an escape character, and used with `t` will result in a tab character. If you want to use the ugly Windows backslash paths, use ``\\``.